# fit movies on dvd, working but style/code questions

Tags: prolog, knapsack-problem

I made a prolog program to show me the best way of fitting stuff on dvd's. The questions are in the comments of the code for reference which I'll paste below, but it boils down to this:

1. Is there a sort of inverted cut operator  to make it search for more although it already matches? See fitexact, something like fitexact(Size,Sum,L,L):-Sum
2. What's the best way to keep track of already processed movies? I retract them but wonder how to do it without that.
3. fitfuzzy uses an `if` `then` construct. I'm not sure what to think of them, it feels weird in prolog. Trying to make it recursive left me horribly confused however :)

```
    % given a list of movies and sizes, try to fit them all onto dvd's
    % wasting as little space as possible.

    % set the dvd size
    dvdsize(4812).

    % sum of all movies in the db
    movies_size(Size) :- findall(S, movie(_,S), LS), sum_list(LS,Size).

    % count of all movies in the db
    movies_count(Count) :- findall(S, movie(_,S), LS), length(LS,Count).

    % see which ones fit exactly
    % this is where i got into trouble, the original idea was to make
    % it like the fuzzy search below but i don't understand how i can 
    % express 'when there are no more movies which make an exact fit,
    % and the sum is smaller then the dvdsize the list is ok too'. 
    fitexact(Movies) :- dvdsize(Size), fitexact(Size, 0, [], Movies).

    % Stop when there's a perfect fit
    % so here i tried Size,Sum and Sum<Size in the body. That obviously
    % doesn't work since it instantly matches. 
    fitexact(Size, Size, Movies, Movies).
    % since otherwise the same movies show up on different dvd's i 
    % thought it would be best to delete them after they fitted. 
    % if I don't want to do that, what's the best way to make sure once
    % a movie is processed it won't show up again? Should it have an extra
    % flag like processed(movie(name,size,processed) or should i assert 
    % done dvd's and see if they're already in them? I wonder how long this
    % all would take since it's already quite slow as is.
    %% :-
    %%  forall(member(Movie,Movies), retract(movie(Movie,_))). %%, !.

    % Otherwise keep filling
    fitexact(Size, Sum, Acc, Movies) :-
      movie(Movie, MovieSize),
      \+ member(Movie, Acc), % no doubles!
      NewSum is Sum + MovieSize,
      NewSum =< Size,
      fitexact(Size, NewSum, [Movie|Acc], Movies). 

    removedvd(DVD) :- 
      forall(member(Movie,DVD),retract(movie(Movie,_))).

    % do a fuzzy fit, try exact fits with decreasing size when
    % there are no exact fits.
    fitfuzzy(DVD) :- dvdsize(Size), fitfuzzy(DVD,Size,0).
    fitfuzzy(_,Size,Size) :- movies_size(Size), !.
    fitfuzzy(_,Size,Size) :- dvdsize(Size), !.
    fitfuzzy(DVD,Size,Wasted) :-
      CheckSize is Size - Wasted,
    % this feels like a horrible way to do this. I very much like suggestions
    % about how to make it recursive or better in general.
      ( fitexact(CheckSize, 0, [], DVD)
      -> removedvd(DVD) 
      ;  NewWasted is Wasted + 1, 
         write('fitfuzzy: Increasing wasted space to '), write(NewWasted), nl,
         fitfuzzy(DVD,Size,NewWasted)
      ).

    status :-
      movies_count(MoviesLeft),
      movies_size(MoviesSize), 
      write('Movies left: '), write(MoviesLeft), nl,
      write('Size left  : '), write(MoviesSize), nl.

    burnloop :-
     movies_count(C), C>0,
     fitfuzzy(DVD),
     status,
     write('DVD = '), print(DVD),nl, nl,
     burnloop.

    % movies.db contains a list of movie(Name,Size). statements. It also
    % must have :- dynamic(movie/2). on top for retract to work.
    go :-
     ['movies.db'],
     burnloop.
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a general comment: Instead of keeping track of *processed* movies, I find it much more natural to first obtain (for example, via findall/3) the list of movies that *still need to* be processed, and then simply work this list off. So you have `burn_dvd(List0, DVD, List)`, which takes a list of movies (possibly in combination with their sizes, say as terms of the form `movie_size(Name, Size)`) as its first argument, constructs a single DVD (by selecting as many movies from List0 as fit on a single DVD, for example after sorting the list by size etc.), and the third argument is the list of remaining movies. You then have a natural extension burn_dvds(List, DVDs) which simply constructs DVDs until no more movies remain:

```
burn_dvds([], []) :- !.
burn_dvds(Movies0, [DVD|DVDs]) :-
    burn_dvd(Movies0, DVD, Movies),
    burn_dvds(Movies, DVDs).
```

No assert/1 or retract/1 is necessary for this. Multiple solutions are possible if burn_dvd/3 non-deterministically constructs a single DVD, which is what you may want and which also seems natural.

Using if-then-else is perfectly OK, however, everything that can be expressed by pattern matching should be expressed by pattern matching, since it usually yields more general and also more efficient code.

format/2 may help you too with output: Instead of:

```
write('Movies left: '), write(MoviesLeft), nl
```

you can write:

```
format("Movies left: ~w\n", [MoviesLeft])
```

In general, manual output is rarely needed as you can always let the toplevel print solutions for you. In our case, burn_dvds/2 naturally emits the list of DVDs as its answer when you query it.

Comment: ok, I should make a list from them thanks for pointing that out. Regarding multiple solutions, do you mean permutations of a created dvd? I'd like to avoid that if possible, that's why I retracted them.

Comment: Not (only) permutations, but there are clearly many ways of constructing single DVDs that still lead to non-isomorphic solutions. For example, when 2 movies have exactly the same size, you can either fit one or the other on any of two DVDs that still have enough space. Using side-effects like assert/1 and retract/1 gets in the way of nice declarative solutions that allow you to easily explore such different variations by using Prolog's natural search strategy.

Comment: yes i think i noticed these side effects when using retract in the same functor, see the commented forall statement in fitexact. Placing it outside of that however speed things up greatly since in the beginning there are lots of movies which will fit so there's lot's fever to check on the next invocation. It's funny to see that work with the output statements, you'll see fitfuzzy first very slowly counting, then increasing until there are some 30 hard to fit (>4000mb) left and then slowing down again for these last ones. Well, not the counting itself but the time it takes to find a best fit.

Comment: i've made a version which uses lists now although it still uses a somewhat clumsy removedvd functor to get to the remaining ones. The problem is that they don't all fit so i'm left with a couple which need adjusting the available space.

Comment: and i have a hard time keeping a remaining list in the functor parameters of fitexact to get rid of that. Trying to find a stop recursion match i mean by that. Anyway. I'll keep playing with it but it's fine as is know, it's faster then above and i've compiled it to native code to print me a list of dvds. Prolog is really neat :)

Comment: This is the adjusted code. I like having format statement in fitall for debugging and seeing progress but the other way works fine too. Still a bit of work in progress while i check out the other examples. Thanks people, you rock. http://axel3.home.xs4all.nl/fit.pro

Comment: there's just too many combinations to work out properly so my problem should have been find the next best match instead of the perfect. I'm looking at the clpfd code for a better solution then 39 dvds in about 10sec. With 150 items it uses way to many ram when i don't clean up in between otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want things to behave as if you kept asking for another solution after each one is provided, but gather them all up into a list, `findall` is what you want.
2. If this is all happening within a single query, you could pass around a list of used movies.  For example, burn loop would take as an argument the list of movies used so far; fitfuzzy would take that list & fill in a new version with the movies for that DVD added, and you'd pass that new list to burnloop.  Or, since DVD has new movies in it, write a new predicate to add the movies in DVD to the old list to make the new one.
3. What if you let fitexact proceed as it currently does, but also keep the list of movies that came closest to the DVD size, so that instead of failing when doesn't fill the DVD exactly, it yields that list?

Comment: thanks, i wondered how to collect things. I should read lpn instead of skimming over it.. instead of findall i think select and setof is neat. I think it will even fix my first prolog program, which was an xkcd menu order puzzle.

Comment: like combining terms in a findall for example; `findall([_,Size], (movie(_,Size), Size > 4000), R)`

Answer (score 1):

A 'best practice rule' of Prolog says that assert/retract should be avoided except when it's **absolutely** required (i.e. when there is no a declarative approach).

Here a program using select/3 to generate all combinations

```
movie(a, 10).
movie(b, 3).
movie(c, 5).
movie(d, 6).
movie(e, 10).

dvdsize(20).

burn(Best) :-
    findall(N-S, movie(N,S), L),
    dvdsize(Max),
    setof(Wasted-Sequence, fitmax(L, Max, Wasted, Sequence), All),
    All = [Best|_],
    maplist(writeln, All).

fitmax(L, AvailableRoom, WastedSpace, [Title|Others]) :-
    select(Title - MovieSize, L, R),
    MovieSize =< AvailableRoom,
    RoomAfterMovie is AvailableRoom - MovieSize,
    fitmax(R, RoomAfterMovie, WastedSpace, Others).

fitmax(_, WastedSpace, WastedSpace, []).
```

output:

```
?- burn(X).
0-[a,e]
0-[e,a]
1-[a,b,d]
1-[a,d,b]
1-[b,a,d]
1-[b,d,a]
1-[b,d,e]
1-[b,e,d]
1-[d,a,b]
1-[d,b,a]
1-[d,b,e]
1-[d,e,b]
1-[e,b,d]
1-[e,d,b]
2-[a,b,c]
2-[a,c,b]
2-[b,a,c]
2-[b,c,a]
2-[b,c,e]
2-[b,e,c]
2-[c,a,b]
2-[c,b,a]
2-[c,b,e]
2-[c,e,b]
2-[e,b,c]
2-[e,c,b]
4-[a,d]
4-[d,a]
4-[d,e]
4-[e,d]
5-[a,c]
5-[c,a]
5-[c,e]
5-[e,c]
6-[b,c,d]
6-[b,d,c]
6-[c,b,d]
6-[c,d,b]
6-[d,b,c]
6-[d,c,b]
7-[a,b]
7-[b,a]
7-[b,e]
7-[e,b]
9-[c,d]
9-[d,c]
10-[a]
10-[e]
11-[b,d]
11-[d,b]
12-[b,c]
12-[c,b]
14-[d]
15-[c]
17-[b]
20-[]
X = 0-[a, e].
```

Comment: ok, I can work it out i think. I should keep in mind that when you use `findall(N-S, movie(N,S), L), ...` prolog doesn't calculate N-S. I'm just starting with it and that confuses me. Also I never heard of select and maplist, so I'll go on reading more about them and others. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer was 'quick and dirty', and soon shows its limits, as the number of movies grows. Here a better way to find the *best* fit, and a comparison with previous answer (reformulated as required by test).

The key to optimize is suggested by the tag *knapsack*, that rightly Axel used when posted the question. I've searched in CLP(FD) support an appropriate way of tackle the problem, here it is:

```
:- [library(clpfd)].

%%  use CLP(FD) to find best fit
%
burn_knapsack(Best, Wasted) :-
    dvdsize(Max),
    findall(Title - Size, movie(Title, Size), Movies),
    knaps(Movies, Max, Best, Wasted).

knaps(Movies, Max, Best, Wasted) :-
    findall([Flag, Title, Size],
        (Flag in 0..1, member(Title - Size, Movies)), AllMovies),
    transpose(AllMovies, [ToBurn, Titles, Sizes]),

    Actual #=< Max,
    scalar_product(Sizes, ToBurn, #=, Actual),
    labeling([max(Actual)], [Actual|ToBurn]),
    findall(Title, (nth1(I, ToBurn, 1),
            nth1(I, Titles, Title)), Best),
    Wasted is Max - Actual.

%%  compute all combinations of movies that fit on a dvd
%   it's a poor man clpfd:scalar_product/4
%
burn_naive(Best, Wasted) :-
    dvdsize(Max),
    findall(Title - Size, movie(Title, Size), Movies),
    naive(Movies, Max, Best, Wasted).

naive(Movies, Max, Best, Wasted) :-
    setof(Wasted-Sequence, fitmax(Movies, Max, Wasted, Sequence), [Wasted-Best|_]).

fitmax(L, AvailableRoom, WastedSpace, [Title|Others]) :-
    select(Title - MovieSize, L, R),
    MovieSize =< AvailableRoom,
    RoomAfterMovie is AvailableRoom - MovieSize,
    fitmax(R, RoomAfterMovie, WastedSpace, Others).
fitmax(_, WastedSpace, WastedSpace, []).

%%  run test with random generated list
%
%   From,To are num.of.movies
%   SzMin, SzMax min/max+1 of each movie size
%
test_performance(From, To, DvdSize, SzMin, SzMax) :-
    forall((between(From, To, NumMovies),
        gen_movies(NumMovies, SzMin, SzMax, Movies)
           ),
           (   (   NumMovies < 11
           ->  test(naive, Movies, DvdSize)
           ;   true
           ),
           test(knaps, Movies, DvdSize)
           )).
test(Method, Movies, DvdSize) :-
    time(once(call(Method, Movies, DvdSize, Best, Wasted))),
    writeln((Method, Best, Wasted)).

gen_movies(NumMovies, SzMin, SzMax, Movies) :-
    findall(Title-Size,
        (   between(1, NumMovies, Title),
            random(SzMin, SzMax, Size)
        ), Movies).
```

I've limited the test for *naive* to less than 11 movies, to avoid stack overflow

```
?- test_performance(8,20, 30, 3,7).
% 93,155 inferences, 0,140 CPU in 0,140 seconds (100% CPU, 665697 Lips)
naive,[1,2,3,5,6],0
% 235,027 inferences, 0,159 CPU in 0,159 seconds (100% CPU, 1481504 Lips)
knaps,[2,3,5,6,8],0
% 521,369 inferences, 0,782 CPU in 0,783 seconds (100% CPU, 666694 Lips)
naive,[1,2,3,4,5,6],0
% 163,858 inferences, 0,130 CPU in 0,131 seconds (100% CPU, 1255878 Lips)
knaps,[3,4,5,6,7,9],0
% 1,607,675 inferences, 2,338 CPU in 2,341 seconds (100% CPU, 687669 Lips)
naive,[1,2,3,4,7,8],0
% 184,056 inferences, 0,179 CPU in 0,180 seconds (100% CPU, 1027411 Lips)
knaps,[5,6,7,8,9,10],0
% 227,510 inferences, 0,156 CPU in 0,156 seconds (100% CPU, 1462548 Lips)
knaps,[5,6,8,9,10,11],0
% 224,621 inferences, 0,155 CPU in 0,155 seconds (100% CPU, 1451470 Lips)
knaps,[6,7,8,9,10,11,12],0
% 227,591 inferences, 0,159 CPU in 0,159 seconds (100% CPU, 1434836 Lips)
knaps,[5,7,9,10,11,12,13],0
% 389,764 inferences, 0,263 CPU in 0,263 seconds (100% CPU, 1482017 Lips)
knaps,[5,8,9,10,12,13,14],0
% 285,944 inferences, 0,197 CPU in 0,198 seconds (100% CPU, 1448888 Lips)
knaps,[8,9,10,12,13,14,15],0
% 312,936 inferences, 0,217 CPU in 0,217 seconds (100% CPU, 1443891 Lips)
knaps,[10,11,12,14,15,16],0
% 343,612 inferences, 0,238 CPU in 0,238 seconds (100% CPU, 1445670 Lips)
knaps,[12,13,14,15,16,17],0
% 403,782 inferences, 0,277 CPU in 0,278 seconds (100% CPU, 1456345 Lips)
knaps,[11,12,13,15,16,17],0
% 433,078 inferences, 0,298 CPU in 0,298 seconds (100% CPU, 1455607 Lips)
knaps,[14,15,16,17,18,19],0
% 473,792 inferences, 0,326 CPU in 0,327 seconds (100% CPU, 1451672 Lips)
knaps,[14,15,16,17,18,19,20],0
true.
```

Comment: yes I noticed that, my movie.db contains 156 movies and testing with that is very slow. I was scared of memory usage also but that seems to grow very slowly. Hence retract again but now I know it's better not to do that. I will need some time to study your examples..

Comment: i should add, i'm using gprolog and am aware of it's differences regarding libraries and clpfd although i can manage i think. I don't have transpose however. I know there's a compat include so I'll see if that works out or maybe i should compile swi?

Comment: transpose it's accessory, and not too difficult to code: you can grab from SWI-Prolog CLP(FD). see [here](http://www.di.univaq.it/formisano/CLPASP/gknapsack.pl) for scalar_product

Comment: I think you perfectly answered my question since it all started with the first question. I think if in the original code fitfuzzy kept it's previous waste value and maybe use select instead of database access it will be a lot faster then it is this will be fun working out, thanks very  much for your examples and insights!

Comment: I would like to add that especially if you are a beginner in Prolog, SWI is by far the most convenient system to use in my opinion: It has make/0, a graphical tracer (?- gtrace, Goal), and other great toplevel features (help/1 etc.).

Comment: @mat: GProlog CLP implementation it's faster, while SWI-Prolog CLP (fully Prolog) it's more complete. So selecting between these we must balance these factors...

Comment: Yes, I recommend to start developping in SWI because it is more convenient, and if it turns out to be too slow, to switch or delegate parts to other systems.

Comment: I've been rewriting it several times now with lists without looking at the examples given since i'm just starting with prolog and this is a fun problem to learn from. I still get stuck but i'm sure i'll work that out eventually. Prolog is really neat :) Maybe i should install emacs, i've used that before as a sort of ide, i bet it has a prolog mode. Regarding implementation i don't care that much yet for thing like graphics or modules (although gprolog is implementing that), the basic stuff is hard enough to get my mind around as is :)

Comment: graphical tracer sounds like fun though, tracing with huge lists on a 80x25 terminal is no fun. It does really help understanding how prolog solves things however and showed me several times why things gave me a stack overflow. Let's install both indeed :)

Comment: Yes, the latest Emacs versions have a really great Prolog mode, and as of Emacs 24.1., you can also install ediprolog with M-x list-packages, which gives you transparent interaction with SWI-Prolog from within Emacs buffers.